# Lambda trigger a function itself

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Hello I have a `laravel` app with `serverless` architecture. I'm getting an error:

`cURL error 28: Failed to connect to fnhxdorrd22l.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com port 443 after 7502 ms: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://fnhxdorrdl22.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/oauth/token`

Is there any configuration need for this or any inbound rules in order to call a function inside a function? BTW, it's working if it's a simple call or request without any call or trigger to other route or third parties.

Serverless.yml

```
service: laravel

provider:
    name: aws
    # The AWS region in which to deploy (us-east-1 is the default)
    region: ap-southeast-1
    # The stage of the application, e.g. dev, production, staging… ('dev' is the default)
    stage: dev
    profile: serverless
    runtime: provided.al2
    lambdaHashingVersion: 20201222321

package:
    # Directories to exclude from deployment
    patterns:
        - '!node_modules/**'
        - '!public/storage'
        - '!resources/assets/**'
        - '!storage/**'
        - '!tests/**'
        - 'storage/oauth-private.key'
        - 'storage/oauth-public.key'

functions:
    # This function runs the Laravel website/API
    web:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        vpc:
          securityGroupIds:
            - sg-042d6942052649ad59b0bc0
          subnetIds:
            - subnet-2c1464319824244
            - subnet-474851e914424e4
            - subnet-4424429f48129d7

        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80-fpm}
        events:
            - httpApi: '*'
    # This function lets us run artisan commands in Lambda
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-80} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer
```

Comment: Is that an API Gateway URL? Please provide more details on what you are trying to do. Also, is the Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: Yes, that's an API Gateway URL. Same VPC with Lambda and RDS. @MarkB, Added my serverless configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lambda function configured to run in a VPC does not get a public IP address ever (regardless of the VPC public IP settings). The API Gateway URL is a public URL on the Internet. That API Gateway URL doesn't exist inside the VPC. In order for the Lambda function to make a connection to that URL the function has to be configured to run in a private VPC subnet that has a route to a NAT Gateway.

Comment: But I can access different routes without any problem at all with my current configuration, Lambda function was inside on a VPC with an IGW connected to it. The only problem is when the method is called with call to third parties or dependent to any other route, the error is shown.

Comment: I think I understand now, even tho I connected to a private subnet with IGW connected, the lambda function still can't connect to internet? Am I right?

Comment: A subnet with an IGW is called a public subnet, not a private subnet. An IGW only works with resources that have public IP addresses assigned to them. Since the Lambda function doesn't have a public IP address assigned to it, it cannot use the IGW. So the Lambda function cannot connect to the Internet with only an IGW. The Lambda function has to have a NAT Gateway to access the Internet.

Comment: It can only connect to the private subnets, but can't connect outside of the VPC.